# En qué tipo de variable guardo una consulta de agrupación

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Cómo recupero una consulta group by, ya que esta devuelve dos tipos de valores, o sea objeto por un lado y un entero asociado a este que es un contador, por lo menos en mi caso.
Estoy usando Mysql y Hibernate. La consulta la tengo que hacer a una tabla llamada `DiasInhabilitados`, la cual se compone de tres columnas: `id`, `dia`, `numeroBox`.
La consulta en sql es: `select *,count(dia) from diasinhabilitados group by dia`.
En hql todavía no la hice pero debe ser muy similar. Devuelve los distintos días que registra esa tabla y además el campo count(dia) que es el número de veces que aparece ese día, como se ve acá:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es cómo recupero esa consulta de agrupación. Qué sería una lista? Y el valor del contador donde se almacena? Qué tipo de variable me devuelve el método donde realizo la consulta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes crear un bean, algo así:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class DiasInhabilitadosBean {

    private Long        id;
    private Timestamp   dia;
    private Integer     numeroBox;
    private Integer     countDia;

    Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    Timestamp getDia() {
        return dia;
    }

    void setDia(Timestamp dia) {
        this.dia = dia;
    }

    Integer getNumeroBox() {
        return numeroBox;
    }

    void setNumeroBox(Integer numeroBox) {
        this.numeroBox = numeroBox;
    }

    Integer getCountDia() {
        return countDia;
    }

    void setCountDia(Integer countDia) {
        this.countDia = countDia;
    }

}
```

Luego devuelves `List<DiasInhabilitadosBean>`.

Si haces la consulta sin hql te va a devlver un `List<Object[]>` que debes iterar y en cada iteración crear tu bean y meterlo en tu list. Si haces el mapeo bien y usas hql te devlverá directamente `List<DiasInhabilitadosBean>`.

Comment: primero quiero mencionar que la explicación fue muy clara!! El programa compila así que parece ser que el mapeo está bien, inclusive pido la lista DiasInhabilitadosBean  por consola de salida y me devuelve la lista de objetos con el cógido hash pero cuando quiero acceder a alguna propiedad, por ej. agrupadoPorFecha().get(10).getCountDia() me lanza esta excepción: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to modelo.DiasInhabilitadosBean. Ahora voy a pegar el mapeo y el método de la consulta

Comment: Porque te devuelve `List<Object[]>`. Pide `agrupadoPorFecha().get(10)[2]` o algo así y te devolverá valor. Solo somo apunte - no publiques respuestas - añade a tu pregunta original.

Comment: Ahora si, capo!! Me devuelve el valor del campo `countDia`, pero lo necesito en `DiasInhabilitadosBean` para poder acceder a los demás atributos. O sea tengo problemas para hacer el cast. Esto por ej.  `agrupadoPorFecha().get(longitud-1)[1]` devuelve el valor  de del campo `countDia` en la última posición, pero por qué solo el atributo `countDia`. Me darías una mano con el cast?

Comment: ahora entendí, no hay que hacer ningún cast, las propiedades de `DiasInhabilitadosBean` son los elementos del array, y en el orden en que están en el select de la consulta. Te agradezco mucho!, hacía rato que quería hacer esto del group by,

Comment: Había votado pero no sabía que debía aceptar la respuesta, soy muy nuevo. Saludo!

Answer (score 0):

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="modelo.DiasInhabilitadosBean" table="diasinhabilitados">
      <id name="id" type="integer">
            <column name="id"/>
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="numeroBox" type="integer">
            <column name="numeroBox" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="dia" type="date">
            <column name="dia" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="countDia" type="integer">
            <column name="countDia" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

```
public List<DiasInhabilitadosBean> agrupadoPorFecha(){
        SessionFactory sesion=NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session;
        session=sesion.openSession();
        Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
        Query q=session.createQuery("select di,count(dia) from DiasInhabilitados di group by dia");
        List<DiasInhabilitadosBean> listDiasInhabBean=q.list();
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        return listDiasInhabBean;
    }
```